# WordPress and React how to integrate?

Tags: rest-api

I am new to this. I am good at WordPress things but just wondering the possibilities with react integration. These are my doubts

1. If I develop a react app is it only possible to connect them via REST API? Is there is possibility deploy it as WordPress plugin.
2. I not sure, Gutenberg is created with react js? So is it possible to create a front form that allows adding adding custom post type with react js. I am aware of WordPress way but curious about the possibility with doing to it with react.

Please help. also if you have any reference links please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Frontity, it's a React framework for integrating with WP https://frontity.org/

However, if you want to build this I think you should be familiar with React and JSX

Comment: Hello, Thanks. .it's integration in reversed way. React app will be the main app while WordPress will be secondary. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by reversed, because the whole idea of the Rest API is to enable Wordpress to be a headless CMS, meaning you build the frontend in React, but yes, the React app will be the main app and Wordpress will just serve as the back-end CMS

Comment: Yeah. I found the react cool but it's not possible to use it in reversed way. I was checking if it can be utilized to improve the wordpress functionality. thanks

Comment: I have not tried to use React with Wordpress yet, but I think you can do a lot of custom functionalities in node with it with the Rest API, you just need to know how to modify the data that the API provides.